# NPE on SupportMapFragment

Tags: android, google-maps, nullpointerexception, android-maps-v2, supportmapfragment

I successfully built a map-fragment with android maps v2 and it works fine on my smartphone. now i plugged in my tablet and i get a NPE when i try to launch the map-activity. I am totally clueless at the moment; not even knowing what the source of the error may be. can anyone help? thx

**OnCreate of map-activity:**

```
FragmentManager myFragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
    SupportMapFragment mySupportMapFragment = (SupportMapFragment)myFragmentManager.findFragmentById(R.id.customer_map_fragment);
    mMap = mySupportMapFragment.getMap();
    mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);                 <-- line 103 with the NPE
    mMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_NORMAL);
```

**customer_map_activity.xml:**

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
         android:layout_width="match_parent"
         android:layout_height="match_parent" >
<fragment
        android:id="@+id/customer_map_fragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        class="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"/>
</FrameLayout>
```

**Logcat:**

```
08-12 11:08:27.449: E/AndroidRuntime(3562): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
08-12 11:08:27.449: E/AndroidRuntime(3562): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.cocus.salesapp/com.cocus.salesapp.TestCustomerMapActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
08-12 11:08:27.449: E/AndroidRuntime(3562):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2185)
08-12 11:08:27.449: E/AndroidRuntime(3562):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2210)
08-12 11:08:27.449: E/AndroidRuntime(3562):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:142)
08-12 11:08:27.449: E/AndroidRuntime(3562):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1208)
08-12 11:08:27.449: E/AndroidRuntime(3562):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
08-12 11:08:27.449: E/AndroidRuntime(3562):     at  android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
08-12 11:08:27.449: E/AndroidRuntime(3562):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4931)
08-12 11:08:27.449: E/AndroidRuntime(3562):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
08-12 11:08:27.449: E/AndroidRuntime(3562):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
08-12 11:08:27.449: E/AndroidRuntime(3562):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:791)
08-12 11:08:27.449: E/AndroidRuntime(3562):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:558)
08-12 11:08:27.449: E/AndroidRuntime(3562):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
08-12 11:08:27.449: E/AndroidRuntime(3562): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
08-12 11:08:27.449: E/AndroidRuntime(3562):     at com.fghj.salesapp.TestCustomerMapActivity.onCreate(TestCustomerMapActivity.java:103)
```

**edit:**
on phone its running on portrait only. on tablet it is forced to use landscape.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may learn about the reason via call to [`GooglePlayServicesUtil.isGooglePlayServicesAvailable`](http://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/common/GooglePlayServicesUtil.html#isGooglePlayServicesAvailable%28android.content.Context%29).

It will return you an int value which you can compare with [`ConnectionResult` constants](http://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/common/ConnectionResult.html).

Comment: im checking that in my onResume. looks like i have to move it to the onCreate then!?

Comment: @bofredo I'd rather do this check in an `Activity` that starts this `Activity`, which contains `MapFragment` and instead of starting it, show a dialog, that map cannot be viewed. Depends on if there is such place in your code, but yes: do this before trying to obtain `GoogleMap` reference and make conditions on when `GoogleMap` reference is null.

Comment: that is odd. my phone returns a "0" while my tablet returns a "2".

Comment: `SERVICE_VERSION_UPDATE_REQUIRED`

Comment: ahh ok, now i get in which direction my problem is heading. Thx alot! i didnt know it was this borrowed tablet with cyanogen-mod causing trouble :/

Comment: will try to build a service-check at where i launch the mapActivity then